# Making the fill each region so I only have 1 bar per year

Tags: r, bar-chart, fill, col

My data is structured as
Year Region1 Region1 Region2 ..Region 10
1991 2000   3000    4000
...  ...     ...     ....
2020 ...    ...      ...

I wanted to create a bar graph where the X values would be the years and every year only has 1 bar but the fill is colored by region, the y values would just be assigned from the numbers in the region.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wskjn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKvpd.png)

Comment: To give us access to the data, use `dput(data)`. You will want to `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Comment: Maybe consider a reshape to the dataset with `gather` from tidyr. 

`longDF <- DF %>% gather(Year, Population, BigBend:SanDiego)`